# (Appium-Jasmine) How to ignore splash screen or wait until finished

Tags: android, cordova, jasmine, appium, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to test a Cordova hybrid app with Appium. I have setup the environment and I can launch a test. But if I try to find a element, I have an error because the app lauch the splash screen. I'm using `cordova-splash-screen` plugin and I'm hidding it manually in my `index.js`.

This is my `package.json`:

```
  "appium": "appium",
  "appium-doctor": "appium-doctor",
  "test:android": "wdio ./config/wdio.android.conf.js",
```

My `wdio.shared.conf.js`:

```js
exports.config = {
  // ====================
  // Runner and framework
  // Configuration
  // ====================
  runner: 'local',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    // Updated the timeout to 30 seconds due to possible longer appium calls
    // When using XPATH
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
  },
  sync: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  deprecationWarnings: true,
  bail: 0,
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  reporters: ['spec'],

  // ====================
  // Appium Configuration
  // ====================
  services: ['appium'],
  appium: {
    // For options see
    // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
    args: {
      // For arguments see
      // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
    },
    // Esto sirve para que coja la versión local de appium y no la global
    command: 'appium'
  },

  port: 4723,

  // ====================
  // Some hooks
  // ====================
  beforeSession: (config, capabilities, specs) => {
    require('@babel/register');
  }
};
```

My `wdio.android.conf.js`:

```js
const {config} = require('./wdio.shared.conf');

// ============
// Specs
// ============
config.specs = [
  './test/specs/*.js'
];

// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// For all capabilities please check
// http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities
config.capabilities = [
  {
    // The defaults you need to have in your config
    platformName: 'Android',
    maxInstances: 1,
    // For W3C the appium capabilities need to have an extension prefix
    // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
    // This is `appium:` for all Appium Capabilities which can be found here
    deviceName: 'any',
    platformVersion: '8.0',
    orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
    // `automationName` will be mandatory, see
    // https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.13.0
    automationName: 'appium',
    appPackage: 'com.nss.ExacctaPrototype',
    appActivity: '.MainActivity',
    // The path to the app
    app: './cordova/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
    // Read the reset strategies very well, they differ per platform, see
    // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/
    noReset: true,
    newCommandTimeout: 240
  }
];

exports.config = config;
```

I was trying to setup a wait in the `wdio.shared.conf.js` but the test script is launched when the splash is showd anyways.

Have someone solved this issue?

Comment: You can use implicit and explicit wait based on your requirement.

Comment: @SubanDhyako can you show me how?

Comment: I can only show you in java. If you want to see how it is done is java, i can show you sample

Comment: @SubanDhyako fine, I can fine that Java conf in Appium docs for Javascript :)